# How do you relatively position a Select2 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I'm creating a d3 data visualization and I want to have an html `<select>` dropdown positioned on top of the `<svg>` that I'm drawing on for d3 (both are inside a parent `<div>`). It's easy enough to add css along the lines of

```
width: 400px;
position: 'relative';
left: 100px;
top: 50px;
```

to the `<select>`, and it works great.

However, I want the dropdown to be searchable, and once I add in the `select2` code `$("#dropdownID").select2();` suddenly the whole dropdown moves below the SVG (but does become searchable). When I inspect it in my browser, the original `<select>` shows up as being in the correct position, but invisible, and a variety of new `select2`-related `<span>`'s (that look like a dropdown) are what is actually showing up below.

I've tried messing with the css for the `<select>`, as well as the `dropdownCss` and `containerCss` options that can be passed into `select2` call, but have only managed to break things further.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still curious if there's a more direct method, but I found an easy enough workaround -- put the `<select>` inside a `<div>`, and apply the positioning to the parent `<div>` (which includes the select2 `<span>`'s that are created).